# Cycling backups with multiple Time Capsules?

Tags: backup, time-capsule

I am using Time Capsule for backing up my Mac at home and like this solution for its convenience (automatic hourly backups in the background, etc.).

I would now like to add an off-site backup to the mix, with the intention of cycling backup media between on-site (used for backup) and off-site (sitting at a safe location) every week or so. (An online backup service is not an option.)

Could I accomplish this by buying a second Time Capsule and just switching between the two (with Open Time Machine Preferences | Select Disk) to effect the cycling. Would this work and/or are there perhaps better (also cheaper) ways to do this?

(I understand that Time Capsule has been designed to be kept running, so the device could perhaps suffer from being turned off/on relatively frequently, i.e. every other week. I also understand that some NAS support [hot swapping](https://serverfault.com/questions/485252/is-using-a-nas-with-hot-swap-disks-an-effective-way-of-cycling-backups), which sounds promising, but isn't really meant to support this scenario either. Creating a [RAID 1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15153) between the Time Capsule -- now to be kept on-site and one from a set of USB drives -- now to be cycled -- sounds elegant but is perhaps more complex than a backup solution ought to be?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time Machine [supports multiple drives](http://macs.about.com/od/backupsarchives/ss/Time-Machine-With-Multiple-Drives-How-To-Use-Two-Or-More-Backup-Drives.htm) since Mountain Lion: that should be sufficient to support the desired backup scenario (1 Time Capsule + 2 cycled USB drives).

(Re answering own question: What can I say ... writing down a question often helps in finding the answer, and I've only recently upgraded from OS X 10.7.)